# R accessing variable column names for subsetting

Tags: r, subset

The following works and does what I want it to do:

```
    dat<-subset(data,NLI.1 %in% NLI)
```

However, I may need to subset via a different column (i.e. NLI.2 and NLI.3). I've tried

```
    NLI_col<-"NLI.1"
    NLI_col<-subset(data,select=NLI_col) 
    dat<-subset(data,NLI_col %in% NLI)
```

Unsurprisingly this doesn't work. How do I use `NLI_col` to achieve the result from the code that does work?

It was requested that I give an example of what `data` looks like. Here:

```
NLI.1<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2)
NLI.2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
NLI.3<-c(NA,35,40,NA,10,NA,31,NA,14,NA,NA,15,17,NA,NA,16,10,15,14,39,17,35,14,14,22,10,15,0,34,23,13,35,32,2,14,10,14,10,10,10,40,10,13,13,10,10,10,13,13,25,10,35,NA,13,NA,10,40,0,0,20,40,10,14,40,10,10,10,10,13,10,8,NA,NA,14,NA,10,28,10,10,15,15,16,10,10,35,16,NA,NA,NA,NA,30,19,14,30,10,10,8,10,21,10,10,35,15,34,10,39,NA,10,10,6,16,10,10,10,10,34,10)
other<-c(NA,NA,511,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,849,NA,NA,NA,NA,1324,1181,832,1005,166,204,1253,529,317,294,NA,514,801,534,1319,272,315,572,96,666,236,842,980,290,843,904,528,27,366,540,560,659,107,63,20,1184,1052,214,46,139,310,872,891,651,687,434,1115,1289,455,764,938,1188,105,757,719,1236,982,710,NA,NA,632,NA,546,747,941,1257,99,133,61,249,NA,NA,1080,NA,645,19,107,486,1198,276,777,738,1073,539,1096,686,505,104,5,55,553,1023,1333,NA,NA,969,691,1227,1059,358,991,1019,NA,1216)

data<-cbind(NLI.1,NLI.2,NLI.3,other)
NLI<-c(10,13)
```

With this, after sub-setting I should get all the rows with tens and thirteens in `data$NLI.3` if `NLI_col <- "NLI.3"`

Since this is relatively trivial I am guessing this is a duplicate question (my apologies), but the hours drag on and I still cant find a solution

Comment: Without seeing `data` it is rather difficult to help. Please provide fake (representative) data or `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: I've added an example. Please let me know if it helps or if you need something more.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/1201032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are unnecessarily using `subset`. Try this:

```
NLI_col <- 'NLI.3'
head(data[,NLI_col] %in% NLI)
##  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
head(data[data[,NLI_col] %in% NLI, ])
##     NLI.1 NLI.2 NLI.3 other
##  5     NA    NA    10    NA
##  17     2     2    10  1005
##  26     2     2    10   801
##  31     2     2    13   572
##  36     2     2    10   980
##  38     2     2    10   843
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am following the question exactly.   Are you asking to just subset the rows of NLI.3 that contain a 10 or a 13?    Is it more complicated than that?

If you just want to get those rows....

```
df[ which(df$NLI.3==10 | df$NLI.3==13 ),]
```

Assuming your data is in a dataframe.   Also, I changed the name of the dataframe from 'data' to 'df' - calling it 'data' can lead to issues.

Comment: That sadly wont work because NLI is a list of variable length. e.g. The user might specify that NLI = c(10,12,13) and then your code would need a means to account for that.

Could you let me know what kind of issues I might run into? I am indeed using 'data' in my code as a variable name for a dataframe and it is a rather large delicate program so I am now concerned.

Comment: yes, after I read r2evans 's answer, I understood the question more.  That's a good answer.      As for 'data'  - it is already the name of a function in the utils package.  It's just better to avoid naming things that are functions names.   I don't think in your case it will do anything bad.  It's just a good habit to make.